# Does it take more power (battery-life) to stream video or to do local video processing?

Tags: embedded, video, 5g

I have a raspberry pi with a camera. I want to take analytics from the video (mostly object detection). This doesn't have to be run in real time and the RPI doesn't need the output of the video processing.
What I'm wondering is if it would take less power on the RPI to do the video processing locally or to stream the video to a server using 5g? I need to have the longest battery life possible.

Comment: Can you define "power"? Do you mean electricity? Processor time? RAM?

Comment: By most power efficient I mean the system that will result in the longest battery life

Comment: This is going to depend on how much energy your specific 5g connection uses and how much energy your processing consumes.  Either could be more efficient depending on the amount of data being sent and the complexity of the processing.

Comment: why don't you measure it?

Comment: There is too little information to answer this question... How long will be the video, are you encoding it? Do you have some free CPU time?

In your case you should look at the energy consumption instead of power, which is the time integral of power (how much power are you consuming for how much time?). Usually communication is considered more power hungry than local processing, but since the RPi is not a powerhouse it will take quite a lot of time to process the video.

Considering that 5G has an insane throughput and is designed to be "mobile friendly" probably is the best option.